# What is wrong with using add_option with Multisite instead of add_blog_option in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I'm working on a new plugin but it's my first to save which will save an option to the database.

Currently I'm using `add_option` and I assumed that
- activation would fail or 
- the wrong value would be saved to the wp_blogID_options table

because I wasn't using `add_blog_option`. All the [posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/add_blog_option) / literature (Wrox, Apress, etc) I've read say I need to use to `add_blog_option`.

But all my testing (and inspecting the SQL table) are proved me wrong. So ... What is wrong with using add_option instead of add_blog_option when making a plugin (that can be single install or multisite)?

To me ... it seems that `add_option` (or even `get_option`) all work fine. I'm guessing the Settings API has some protection wrapper.

However ... that would mean using `add_blog_option` (or get_blog_option) are only for 'purists'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've come to 'learn' is that there are 3 states on plugin activation for a mulitsite setup.

Consider this for a Site Admin who installs a new plugin:

1. Plugin is network activated -  but it needs admin to complete setup (call it stateless)
2. Plugin activated, no 'unique features' per blog and it doesn't need an admin user to complete setup  (call it active)
3. Plugin activated, has unique features per blog and it does need an admin user to complete setup (call it pending)

Scenario 1: you can safely use 'add_option' on plugin activation (or network activation) as the plugin is *stateless*.

Scenario 2: you must use 'add_blog_option' and loop through each blog - if you do *network activation* as the plugin will be *active*.

Scenario 3: you must use 'add_blog_option' and ideally you don't allow *network activation* because the plugin is *pending*.

In my case, my plugin does nothing until the Blog owner creates a page with the shortcode.

Answer (score 4):

`add_blog_option` ultimately calls `add_option` itself to add the option after [switching the context](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) to the supplied blog ID. the difference is that `add_option` will only work in the context of the current blog where `add_blog_option` lets you specify a blog ID that may be different than the current context.

Comment: so it doesn't matter? - unless im trying to activate a plugin from a different blog.